# Label callouts in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

Has anyone been using callout labelling with QGIS, either trunk or stable?

Used for clustered points. That means the point stays where it is, the label maybe moved if required and a leader (plain or pointed) shows the linkage between the label and the point.

How could I do it (you know what I mean, no coding....)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this without any coding but just to follow the points carefully...

1) Download & add Qgis plugin 'Easy Custom Labelling' from Qgis Official repository. Run the first part of the plugin, "generate centroids".

2) Label your layer using 'Labeling' tool & move overlapping labels manually (Using Label Move-Present at Labeling Toolbar) after toggoling editing mode.

3) after saving the necessary edits...run the 'Easy Custom Labelling' plugin and select 'generates Lines from Labels' button (This will create your desired Leader as a separate .shp file).

For safety, when the tool asks for a projection (CRS), use the same as the layer which is being labelled. Your mileage may vary if you choose another.....

Check the snap attached for further understanding...

[image: Custom Label Using Leader in QGIS1.8.0]

...Thanks

Comment: OK, many thanks for pointing this out to me.   The description of the plugin was lacking detail so I had overlooked it. I will explore with the author.    Also I will edit your answer as there was a bit more detail to getting it all to work, fortunately the plugin has safety features for users like me!

Comment: Furthermore, you should go to the 'Advanced' tab of the 'Layer Labeling settings' menu there is the 'Engine setting' button. If you open that dialogue, you will see the option to show all labels, including colliding labels. Thus you will be able to find and move all labels.

Comment: Agreed Gideon, that is important I know.   The plugin homepage http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/EasyCustomLabeling/

Comment: If you contact the author, you could also try to inform him about the bug, that the tool does not allow to change font size and style. (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58763/changing-font-size-when-using-the-easy-custom-labeling-plugin/62300#62300)

I already opened a ticket here: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/7947

Comment: Found this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31484/how-to-add-labels-outside-of-features

Comment: From Regis (I trust I can repeat here) "Hi, thanks for your feedback
I had to unplug that functionnality since there is a  bug  in the dialog raised when changing each label. 
Another bug is that you can't type multi line text in that dialog. 

It tested in 1.9, and it is not resolved. 

I signaled the issue here: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/8003

Feel free to donate or hire someone, since I think this won't be solved in 2.0. It is not a regression, and 2.0 is actually being focusesd on blockers only (help is welcome here to)
Régis"

Comment: Good answer. I recommend also installing the plugin "Memory Layer Saver" (https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/MemoryLayerSaver/) so the labels doesn't disappear when you close the project.

Comment: is something similar to easy custom labeling available for 2.18.7? I can't install the plugin

Comment: @beaver forget that Q I just downloaded it manually from this thread here: https://github.com/haubourg/EasyCustomLabeling/issues/20

Answer (score 5):

Until QGIS 3.8 you can draw line connector using geometry generator as described by *kgjenkins* here:
[GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/kgjenkins/1af82a8ffdc3c99bb886e6cd9cdc298f#file-readme-md)

[image: Geometry generator]

Since QGIS 3.10 you can use built-in support of [label callouts](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog310/#feature-label-callouts).

[image: QGIS changelog]