# QGIS Text Layer Diagrams - Callout Lines

Tags: qgis, labeling, diagram, callout

I've created a set of Text Layer Diagrams as below. Is there a way of giving them callout lines as with labels?

[image]

Comment: Please check this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62760/label-callouts-in-qgis